# Does anyone actually follow or pasken from the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: ashkenazi, kitzur-shulchan-aruch

Given what i've heard that the Kitzur shouldn't be paskened from and or followed halacha lemaaseh, is there anyone who follows the Kitzur practically for halachos? at least for the Yoreh deah, even haezer v'choshen mishpat sections from it? If no one atleast follows it, why learn from it?

Comment: When I was in high school one of my rebbeim said that "if you follow the Kitzur you're doing pretty well." I don't think anyone particularly _doesn't_ follow the kitzur, even if for specific p'sakim we might follow others. The Artscroll KSA quotes the Mishnah Berurah where he differs, for example. If you're looking for a good source to follow halachah l'maaseh, though, you might want to try the Aruch Hashulchan. He writes on all four sections of the Shulchan Aruch, brings halachah l'maaseh, and he was a community rov so his experience answering very practical shailos informs his writing.